# Why is Stack Exchange using my old email address?

Tags: support, email, email-notification

Yesterday, Stack Exchange sent me an email with the [Developer Survey 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017) results. I am importing mail from various addresses, so it was only by chance I noticed it was sent to one of my older emails.

"Wait, this not the email I am using on SE".

I checked my profile, and yup, I changed my email address more than a month ago (In all communities, I have the same profile on all SE sites).

I know SE can send email to the new address as I received some other mail from the site about three weeks ago. So why is just this one email sent to an old address?

Comment: Are you sure it came from us? I wasn't aware of any email that was sent out about the results. As an aside, you do seem to still have your old email address set for notifications in your Preferences.

Comment: @animuson I think that is it, the notification address does indeed look like a different thing. Mystery solved. As for if the email is from you, the sender was "do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email"

Comment: Heh yeah, [apparently you're not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345968/new-feature-email-notification-tells-me-i-signed-up-but-i-did-not). There's usually an internal announcement before emails like this go out so people aren't caught off guard. :P But there *is* another email going around from a third party who blogged about it who's been spamming some users.

Comment: I got this e-mail too. I just deleted it, but on further investigation it does appear to be virtually indistinguishable from a phishing e-mail. If it is really something that came from SO then I'm (more than) a bit disappointed.

Comment: I also got an email about the results. Can't say if it was real or fake.  Email to my knowledge has never been made public on SO since I joined. My gravator for awhile was the leak variety but that's all I can recall